# How to make the "child" pages render normally?

Tags: html, css

I have a home page, and it is rendered as it should - width is 100% and height is 100%. It has a menu (iframe). From this menu I am going to other pages (with the same menu). But when I open another page from the menu, it doesn't have 100% width and height, but the structure of the page is the same, and the styles are the same. How can I fix it?
PFA code of the index.html:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&family=Raleway:wght@500&family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap');

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.background {
    display: table;
    background-color: #01579B;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px;
    background-size: cover;
}

.container {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}

iframe.header {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

iframe.menu {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.logo-picture {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.logo-card {
    display: table;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url("img/logo-background.jpg");
    height: 150px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

ul.menu > li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.logo-link {
    display: inline;
}

.logo-title {
    display: table-cell;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu-card {
    background-color: #558B2F;
    height: 70px;
    display: table;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.logo-title > a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #0D47A1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content-card {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.content-card h1 {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 45px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content-card img {
    width: 100%;
}

.content-card .bold {
    font-weight: 900;
}

.content-card .italic {
    font-style: italic;
}

.content-card > div {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content-card h2 {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.quote {
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-left-color: #FB8C00;
    border-left-style: solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Board games - домашняя страница</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Сайт посвящен настольным играм">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="background" align="center">
            <div class="container">
                <iframe scrolling="no" src="src/header.html" class="header"></iframe>
                <iframe scrolling="no" src="src/menu.html" class="menu"></iframe>
                <div class="content-card">
                    <h1>Зачем взрослые люди играют в настолки?</h1>

                    <img src="img/dangeonsAndDragons.jpg" />

                    <div class="bold italic">Спойлер: потому что это весело.</div>

                    <div class="italic">Настольные игры с начала своей истории были предметом культа, и в наши дни остаются популярным развлечением. И вовсе не только для детей. Говорим о настольных играх, где повышаются ставки, накаляются нервы, а победителю достаются все сокровища мира. С чего начать?</div>

                    <h2>Заглянуть в коробку</h2>

                    <div>Первое, что нужно знать о настольных играх — для них совершенно не обязателен стол. Скорее всего, первые настольные игры появились даже раньше, чем столы: в них можно было играть на земле и на любой относительно ровной поверхности. Это были игры с костями, глиняными табличками, деревянными и каменными фигурками, которые подбрасывались или выкладывались в определенном порядке. В древних цивилизациях Южной Америки, например, были распространены настольные игры-гонки, а славяне играли в «бирюльки» — так называлась целая группа игр с использованием мелких предметов сложной формы. Задача игроков состояла в том, чтобы «выудить» как можно больше фигур с помощью тонкого крючка.</div>

                    <div class="quote">Для настольных игр не нужен тяжелый инвентарь, оборудованная площадка и в большинстве случаев игрокам даже не понадобится двигаться с места.
                    Хорошая настольная игра может сдружить рабочий коллектив, спасти от скуки в долгом путешествии или поднять настроение, когда кажется, что лето в этом году никогда не начнется.</div>

                    <div>Тех, кому кажется, что настолки — развлечение для детей, разубедит история. Поскольку в античных настолках большую роль играл счастливый случай, древние люди придерживались принципа «игры — детям не игрушка». Многие игры имели сакральный, религиозный смысл, а их исход считался предзнаменованием. Определенным фигурам или комбинациям приписывались различные истолкования, и далеко не каждый имел право прикасаться к ящику, где хранился игровой набор. В наши дни культ игры продолжается.</div>

                    <h2>Создать собственный мир</h2>

                    <div>Бум на настольные ролевые игры начался в 1980-х и продолжается по сей день. Сериал «Очень странные дела», который весь собран из отсылок к культуре 1980-х, начинается со сцены, где четверо школьников играют в знаменитую настольную игру Dungeons and Dragons.</div>

                    <img src="img/dangeonsAndDragons2.jpg" />

                    <div>Ролевые настольные игры созданы на основе одноименных компьютерных игр и вселенных RPG, а также книг. Партии в них могут длиться месяцами, а кроме поля и фигур, в игре используются листы персонажа. В этих листах игроки указывают свои характеристики — уровень здоровья, магические и боевые способности, снаряжение, дополнительные бонусы, которые изменяются по ходу игры. Эти изменения определяются бросками костей, а также действиями самих игроков, которые влияют на все происходящее.</div>

                    <div class="quote">Партии в ролевых настольных играх могут длиться неделями и месяцами.
                    Важную роль в таких играх играет ведущий — «мастер», который описывает игровые ситуации.</div>

                    <div>Среди взрослых увлечение играми выходит на новый уровень, и в первую очередь это определяется экономически. Игровые мастера зарабатывают деньги за проведение модулей. Во многих городах, в том числе и в России, для них существуют курсы существуют школы мастеров. Реквизит тоже обходится недешево: например, цены на миниатюры Warhammer достигают десятков тысяч рублей. Кроме того, их коллекционируют и кастомизируют — навык росписи фигурок для настольной игры требует огромной усидчивости и внимательности к деталям.</div>

                    <h2>Стать манчкином-терминатором</h2>

                    <div>Над таким серьезным увлечением грех не посмеяться! Так возникла пародийная серия «Манчкин». «Манчкином» в ролевых играх называют игрока, который играет ради процесса и все усилия бросает на «раскачку» и скоростное прохождение. Фраза «я надену все лучшее сразу» — это про них. Они предпочитают амуницию с большим количеством бонусов, смертоносное оружие, а еще убивают всех, кто попадется под руку, чтобы получить как можно больше сокровищ.</div>

                    <img src="img/munchkin.jpg" />

                    <div>Именно эта жадность и желание стать самым крутым стали движущей силой игры. За время партии можно превратиться из человека в орка и обратно, умереть сто раз и собрать свое снаряжение заново, попросту стащив его у других героев. Участники собирают карты сокровищ и вступают в схватки с монстрами, чтобы пройти на максимальный уровень. В этом помогают не только свойства карт, но и стратегия самих игроков: они могут обманывать друг друга, устраивать засады и наживаться на чужих победах и поражениях. В игре нет поля, а для того, чтобы складывать карты, можно использовать коробку, поэтому играть в нее можно где угодно, даже в дороге.</div>

                    <div>Первое издание «Манчкина» сосредоточилось на клише из фэнтезийных игр, но с тех пор создатели выпустили дополнения в самых разных стилистиках: здесь есть пираты, супергерои, инопланетяне. Все колоды можно совмещать, поэтому в одной игре радиоактивный эльф может встретиться с зомби-детективом и образовать с ним команду… до тех пор, пока это будет им выгодно.</div>

                    <h2>Не довольствоваться малым</h2>

                    <div>Для тех, кто предпочитает наживаться системно, существуют экономические настольные игры. У них тоже богатая история: в XIX веке печатные настольные игры (в России их называли «картонажные») пришли в педагогику. С их помощью дети осваивали счет и чтение, изучали историю, географию, биологию, также знакомились с важными событиями современности, например, выставками достижений науки и искусства. В 1904 году американка Лиззи Меги придумала игру The Landlord’s Game, которая должна была познакомить детей с важностью труда и основами экономики. Спустя еще 30 лет патент на игру купили предприниматели братья Паркеры, которые превратили ее в известную нам «Монополию».</div>

                    <img src="img/monopolia.jpg" />

                    <div>«Монополия» выпускает издания на разную тематику — от «Игры престолов» до «Гарри Поттера». Основа остается классической: квадратная доска, на которой по периметру обозначены «предприятия», кубики, набор карт и фишки. В специальных изданиях фишки всегда особенные — например, в «русской Монополии» есть матрешка и пуанты. Поэтому перед партией в «Монополию» убедитесь в том, что у вас есть достаточно места, чтобы разложить доску, и поверхность достаточно стабильная, чтобы фишки не слетали с игрового поля.</div>

                    <div>Если игровое поле «Монополии» кажется пройденным вдоль и поперек, можно перейти к играм, в которых есть поле генерируется каждый раз заново. К их числу принадлежит «Шакал», игра, которую придумали в России в 1970-х годах. В наборе игры более ста фишек, из которых складывается карта острова сокровищ. После создания острова начинается сбор сокровищ, в котором игрокам волей-неволей придется «шакалить». Все же когда речь идет о наживе, идти к победе придется по головам.</div>

                    <div class="italic">Такая воинственная обстановка игр на обогащение полезна с точки зрения психологии коллектива. Настольная игра на работе покажет, как сотрудники реагируют на стрессовые ситуации. Партия в дружеской компании — это способ «спустить пар» и побыть злобным манчкином. Тем более для этого не придется даже вставать с дивана.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PFA code of another page:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&family=Raleway:wght@500&family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap');

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.background {
    display: table;
    background-color: #01579B;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px;
    background-size: cover;
}

.container {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}

iframe.header {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

iframe.menu {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.logo-picture {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.logo-card {
    display: table;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url("img/logo-background.jpg");
    height: 150px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

ul.menu > li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.logo-link {
    display: inline;
}

.logo-title {
    display: table-cell;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu-card {
    background-color: #558B2F;
    height: 70px;
    display: table;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.logo-title > a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #0D47A1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content-card {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.content-card h1 {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 45px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content-card img {
    width: 100%;
}

.content-card .bold {
    font-weight: 900;
}

.content-card .italic {
    font-style: italic;
}

.content-card > div {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content-card h2 {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.quote {
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-left-color: #FB8C00;
    border-left-style: solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Board games - Топ настольных игр</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Сайт посвящен настольным играм">
        <link rel="icon" href="../img/icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="background" align="center">
            <div class="container">
                <iframe scrolling="no" src="header.html" class="header"></iframe>
                <iframe scrolling="no" src="menu.html" class="menu"></iframe>
                <div class="content-card">
                    <div>Раз два три</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First page has `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` and second page has `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">`. Are the first and second page in the same directory?

Comment: @RobMoll no, the second page is in the "src" directory, and the first one is index.html, located in the root directory

Comment: Why do you use `.background {display: table;}`?

Comment: @Azu because in other cases of display property the background didn't cover the whole page (as you can see, there is a lot of content). Display: table was the first working solution.

Comment: @Azu I remember just that I tried some other methods, and they didn't work, and the display: table worked

Comment: @Azu Probably it will be better like that: .background {
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-color: #01579B;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 5px;
}

Comment: @Azu it fixed my problem, thanks!

Comment: Olga, when you use `display:table`, the div will wrap the inner content, so that container with the class `.background` wraps the inner content.